# Function is giving the wrong answer to my equation?

Tags: javascript, function

Doing a Celsius to Fahrenheit converter and reverse. and code seems to be working fine but when I give 20 under the F to C function it returns 2.2222 instead of 68 like it should, does the same with both equations.

```
let num = userInput
let numF = num * 9 / 5 + 32;
let numC = num - 32 * 5 / 9;




 celci = (num) => {
    console.log('Enter temp to convert')

    if (num <= 0 || num >= 0) {
        return numF
    }
    }
 if (num === 'F') {
    celci(num)
    }
```

If I enter F it returns 'Enter temp to convert' like it should, but when I give it a number it returns the completely wrong answer.

Comment: `num - 32 * 5 / 9` ... is `num - (32 * 5 / 9)` ... you need to add brackets ... `(num - 32) * 5 / 9;`

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of operator precedence. `*` and `\` are performed before `+` and `-` (which is the same as for mathematic equations). So in:

```
num - 32 * 5 / 9
```

your equation is effectively:

```
num - (32 * 5 / 9)
```

but should be:

```
(num - 32) * 5 / 9;
```

The first equation should work as the `+` is at the end anyway.

Comment: I would say, as you imply #RobG, don't rely on precedence.  Always bracket operations the way you want the function to work.

Comment: @DavidFreeman—mostly I agree, such as for `a - b * c`, but not always. :-)

Comment: My personal opinion on usage of grouping, is use it wherever there is a potential doubt about your intent.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the precedence of the operators. It is better to use brackets in complex equations.
You should use:

`let numC = (num - 32)* (5/ 9);`